# How do I configure config.yml so that I can install devkit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Aaron>cd /DevKit
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Aaron>cd \DevKit

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb init

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

C:\DevKit>ruby dk.rb install --force
Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed. Please fix 'config.yml'
and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'

C:\DevKit>
```

The config.yml looks like this:

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
```

I am completely stumped I have no clue what to do. Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What's the content of `config.yml`?

Answer (score 24):

Yeah I don't think it could possibly be more vague. Basically, it's asking for one reference to your ruby installation. Mine lives in my Program Files directory since I prefer to keep all installed stuff in one spot, rather than straight on the C drive like is default (I'm on windows).
So, since my Ruby installation path is:
C:\Program Files\Ruby200-x64

My **entire** config.yml file is the following:

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- "C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64"
```

Note, I put my Ruby filepath in quotes because it contains a space. If your path doesn't contain a space, then you won't need it.

I can see this being colossally confusing for a lot of people, so I hope this helps.

**update**
I'm seeing that spaces in file paths causes issues, so I've moved mine back down to the c:\ drive just because I don't want to deal with it. I recommend staying away from spaces in file paths unless you're willing to troubleshoot issues down the line.

Answer (score 13):

So... that file is asking you to point to your ruby installation.

for me... mine looked like:

```
- C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0
```

Answer (score 8):

Write your path to ruby installation folder
The pattern is three dashes then move to next line 
Add another dash, space and path

```
---
- C:\Ruby21-x64
```

(Since you can see three dashes have already been put at the 
end of your config.yml file so you basically need to add the last line)

Comment: You get my vote for being the only answer to explicitly state that the _dash_ and _space_ are required. That is totally unclear in the canned comment in the starter config.yml file.

Comment: Yeah the dash and space were the problem for me. Terrible instructions from the DevKit side.

Answer (score 2):

watch out of blank spaces! My problem was this maybe can be yours too !

Answer (score 2):

You have to use slashes "/" instead of backslashes "\" on windows.
Worked for me on Win7x64