# Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed?

Tags: ruby, devkit

When I try setting the *Devkit* path, I end up with the following error

```
C:\Devkit>ruby dk.rb install
Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed. Please fix 'config.yml'
and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'
```

I cannot resolve this error. Can someone help me?

This is my config.yml file.

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
```

Comment: show your `config.yml`. and have you used the rvm/rbenv?

Comment: @majioa, neither RVM or rbenv work on Windows.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not sure, because even on Windows he can use mingw/cygwin...

Comment: Mingw and Cygwin aren't Windows. They're shells on top of Windows that provide *nix-like functionality. Neither RVM or rbenv work with batch files, so Windows is out. Running them inside the other shells might work, but again, they won't provide the same functionality at the Windows layer that the OP would need.

Comment: I had this issue on server 2012 when I installed devkit and ruby on a user then switched to Administrator and tried to get a ruby console... i had to reinstall ruby then it broke dk. then i couldn't install dk because of this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure config.yml so that I can install devkit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810653/how-do-i-configure-config-yml-so-that-i-can-install-devkit)

Answer (score 36):

Your config.yml file is a [YAML](http://www.yaml.org) file. You need to define a path to our Ruby environment, using the example:

```
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
```

That example is commented out so it's not doing anything on your machine. In "real" YAML you'd use something like:

```
---
- C:/ruby19trunk
- C:/ruby192dev
```

which would define an array of paths, or directories, for your environment. You'll need to figure out where the appropriate paths are, and fill that in.

I'd strongly recommend you read [the YAML documentation](http://www.yaml.org) so you understand what you're doing. Any more, YAML is one of the most commonly used data-serialization formats there is, and you'll encounter it a lot.

Comment: The `- ` at the beginning of the full path is critical and will continue to fail without it being specified (e.g. it isn't just an ASCII bullet list.

Comment: @IshwaryaMurugesan if it helped you please tick next to the answer to accept it.