# Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed. Please fix 'config.yml' and rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'

Tags: ruby, windows, installation

I want to install ruby on windows7 to then use Scout and SASS, I did it by a windows installer but I am initializing it and then intalling for configuring my SASS. I did the

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

without any problem but for

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

I have the error to configure the config.yml file,
my Ruby folder is in the fallowing path:

```
G:\Ruby22-x64
```

here is the screenchot:

[image]

according to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184452/invalid-configuration-or-no-rubies-listed) I wrote this path file in config.yml:

```
# This configuration file contains the absolute path locations of all
# installed Rubies to be enhanced to work with the DevKit. This config
# file is generated by the 'ruby dk.rb init' step and may be modified
# before running the 'ruby dk.rb install' step. To include any installed
# Rubies that were not automagically discovered, simply add a line below
# the triple hyphens with the absolute path to the Ruby root directory.
#
# Example:
#
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
-"G:/Ruby22-x64"
```

I also tried:

```
-G:/Ruby22-x64
```

or

```
-G:/Ruby22-x64/bin
```

and also this:

```
---
-G:\Ruby22-x64
```

I also intalled it in c:\programfiles and then write the path in config.yml still not working.

nothing worked for me,How can I solve it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try:

```
---
- G:\Ruby22-x64
```

The **YAML** syntax says you need the 3 dashes at the top and then both the **dash** and **space** (`-`)

Comment: For those who wish to understand a _little_ bit about why that format's required, the `---` indicates a document header, and the `- `  indicates a member of a sequence or list.

Answer (score 2):

dont get confuse with the YML File ('listed in DevKit Extraction folder') just put the Ruby Directory Name (that u installed on C:/ or your primary disk drive) for me (i installed ruby on C:/ Ruby22-x64) 
you just put that directory name at the end of YML File

### like

- C:/Ruby22-x64
  be careful for white space between Drive name and '- C:/Ruby22-x64'
  like this

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
# ---
# - C:/ruby19trunk
# - C:/ruby192dev
#
---
- "D:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64"
```

you should notice that space, [see this picture for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNT3Q.png)